# Using Rabbitmq DefaultConsumer channel to publish

Tags: rabbitmq

DefaultConsumer has a channel that it binds to and can be acquired with `getChannel()`. Can I use this channel in `handleDelivery` to publish something to another queue or should I create a new factory+connection+channel trifecta and use that to publish? I want to publish an event to another queue when consumer consumes an event from it's queue, just not sure if the consumer channel can be re-used for publishing and if it is safe to do.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use different channels

you should no use the same channel to consume and publish

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that is?

Comment: I got a similar answer on the mailing list but I am not yet sure what exactly is the technical problem behind it.

Comment: If you use the channel in handleDelivery it is in the same thread is it not? Unless accepting messages and publishing  is somehow done in separate threads behind the scenes.

Comment: Publish is asynchronous, the channel could be still busy. Open another channel is cheaper. I suggest to open a new channel outside the consumer scope and use it